# Create a table using `pg_table_def` data in Redshift or DBT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbt

To create a table from all the data in `pg_table_def` that is visible to my user, I tried:

```sql
create table adhoc_schema.pg_table_dump as ( 
  select *
  from pg_table_def
);
```

But it throws an error:

> Column "schemaname" has unsupported type "name"

Any way to create a table from `pg_table_def` or `information_schema.columns`?

Answer (score 1):

Found this from another thread, which seems like it would help.

Amazon considers the internal functions that INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is using Leader-Node Only functions. Rather than being sensible and redefining the standardized INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, Amazon sought to define their own proprietary version. For that they made available another function PG_TABLE_DEF which seems to address the same need. Pay attention to the note in the center about adding the schema to search_path.

Stores information about table columns.

PG_TABLE_DEF only returns information about tables that are visible to the user. If PG_TABLE_DEF does not return the expected results, verify that the search_path parameter is set correctly to include the relevant schemas.

You can use SVV_TABLE_INFO to view more comprehensive information about a table, including data distribution skew, key distribution skew, table size, and statistics.

So using your example code (rewritten to use NOT EXISTS for clarity),

```
SET SEARCH_PATH to '$user', 'public', 'target_schema';

SELECT "column" 
FROM dev.fields f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM PG_TABLE_DEF pgtd
  WHERE pgtd.column = f.field
  AND schemaname = 'target_schema'
);
```

See also,

Official docs on Querying Redshift System Tables: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_querying_redshift_system_tables.html

Comment: If this is sourced from another thread, please be sure to offer a link/citation back to that thread.

Answer (score 0):

pg_table_def is a leader-node system table with some additional data types not supported in user tables.  You will need to cast to text first.

However, this still won't work because pg_table_def is a leader-node table and the table you are creating is a user table stored on the compute nodes.  You will need to pull your source information from tables that are stored on compute-nodes.  Since I don't know what information you are looking for from pg_table_def I cannot say exactly which ones you need but you can start with stv_tbl_perm and join in pg_class and other tables as more info is needed.